# Using processing.py in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, processing

On page below I read that processing.py is in fact "add-on called Python Mode":

https://py.processing.org/tutorials/gettingstarted/

Does it mean that I cannot by any means use processing inside my python code - let's say - in some Anaconda IDE like Spyder? And to run some equivalent of processing sketches in python?

In other words: How to run some non-trivial code like setup() and draw() functions from sketches like: https://py.processing.org/tutorials/p3d/ ?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://discourse.processing.org/t/tutorial-running-python-mode-in-vscode/7716)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't really use processing in python, but there is a python library called `processing-py`, a package like processing. If you modify the code, you can run functions like setup() and draw() like this:

```py
from processing_py import *

def setup():
    global x,y,z
    app = App(200, 200)
    x = width/2
    y = height/2
    z = 0

def draw():
    global x,y,z
    app.translate(x, y, z)
    app.rectMode(CENTER)
    app.rect(0, 0, 100, 100)
```